# C# dynamic statement without dynamic keyword

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a method that returns a string and takes a string:

```
public static string GenerateValidIdentifier(string token)
{
    using (var code = new CSharpCodeProvider())
    {
        return code.CreateValidIdentifier(token);
    }
}
```

and when I call it visual studios is saying that it is a dynamic statement, which I don't want. What's happening here?

Comment: Can you paste the code that invokes this method and the full error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSharpCodeProvider is a method of CodeDomProvider, which is used to dynamically generate code, so it's usage can't be determined at compile-time (statically), so it is instead dynamic. Why are you using the method if it is not for dynamic programming?

Comment: I was just using it to parse reserved words.
And looking at the method it is not marked as dynamic... how would I tell it is a dynamic object?